# Make a hypernym tree for a set of words usint NLTK

Tags: python, tree, nltk

I have a list of words and I'd like to create a nltk.draw() like tree of their relations starting with each word on the bottom and showing all of their hypernyms in increasing generality as you go up all of which will ultimately connect to the 'entity' node. Does anyone know of a function that would allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [random hack](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2009/12/29/visualizing-wordnet-relationships-as-graphs). Looks promising.
Then you could construct a tree with as many 'levels' as you desire.